# Selecting a column in Realm and clicking through the links

Tags: swift, url, realm

I do not know how to solve the problem: there is a database with fields:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class EventsDB: Object {
@objc  dynamic var dataMonth = ""
@objc  dynamic var dataDay = ""
@objc  dynamic var desc = ""
@objc  dynamic var link = ""

}
```

The link column contains links to some events. The SecondController class has a showTutorial function:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import SafariServices

class SecondController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var linkGive: String?
var dayForSearch: String?
var monthForSearch: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let monthForSearch = self.monthForSearch else {
            return
        }

        self.realevents = (try! Realm()).objects(EventsDB.self).filter("dataMonth = '\(monthForSearch)' && dataDay = '\(dayForSearch ?? "0")")
    }
}

func showTutorial(_ which: Int) {
    if let url = URL(string: "\((try! Realm()).objects(EventsDB.self).filter("link"))") {
        let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
        config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true

        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}

var realevents: Results<EventsDB>?
}

extension SecondController: UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    showTutorial(indexPath.row)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return realevents?.count ?? 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        else {
            return UITableViewCell()
    }
    let realevent = realevents?[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = realevent?.desc

    return cell
}
}
```

Q: How do I select the link column and make the application open the links in this column? (What should I enter in the URL (in the showTutorial function)?)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the object with the link in your results array, so all you need to do is read the object from the array and get its link, then transform it into a URL and bail out if any of this fails.

```
func showTutorial(_ index: Int) {
    guard let url = realevents?[index].link.flatMap { URL(string: $0)} else {
        return
    }
    let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
    config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
    present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```